# Creating Crystal report Using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports

I just learner a little how to use CR today and created a report called Report1.rpt using it.
The report is connected to my database using three procedures, called Get_Query1, Get_Query2 and Get_Query3.

In my form application already created using C#, i have button called save to pdf, that will pass a value x to the parameters in the procedure, and then open the report, loading the parameter needed.

The code is the following:

```
private void savepdfToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //IN THIS PART WE GET THE FORM ID, AND SEND IT TO THE PROCEDURE PARAMETER
    int x = ID_FORM;
    if (x == 0)
        x = Get_Form_ID();
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(x));
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_Query_1", sc);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MoM_ID", 339));

    //THE NEXT STEPS

        ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();  
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\nbousaba\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\Report1"; 
        reportDocument.Load(filePath);
        CrystalReportViewer crv = new CrystalReportViewer();
        crv.ReportSource = reportDocument;


}
```

The problem so far, that when i run the code, i get an exception error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in WindowsFormsApplication4.exe
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an
>   exception.

I have tried different codes that i found online, and they are all leading to the same problem.

I also used the following packages

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.ReportSource;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms;
```

Is the problem in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that even after downloading the packages, if you are using visual studio 2013, CR will not function properly until you install the following

```
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824
```

All is working fine now.